# How to add documentation or comment in RakeFile

Tags: ruby, command-line, rake, command-line-arguments

I have one Rakefile:

```
desc 'submodulePull'
task :submodulePull do
  sh 'git submodule update'
  sh 'git submodule foreach git pull'
end
```

I want to add description about submodulePull work.

How do I add documentation/comment/description about command in RakeFile that should ignore by compiler @run time.

Comment: I have more than 10 line of description  .

Answer (score -1):

You're already doing it -- that's what `desc` is, which stands for description.

Comment: Thanks . I am new in writing rakefile. If i have more than 10 line of description  .

Comment: Thanks can you give me example like :  ` desc ' ... ..    new line then text ' `

Comment: sure. `desc 'some line \n some other line \n some other line'`